# adding tk-8.6.8 package for cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I install and run PWgui-6.2 in cygwin, and get this message 
"couldn't load file "/usr/bin/tk86.dll": No such file or directory
    while executing
"load /usr/bin/tk86.dll Tk"
    ("package ifneeded Tk 8.6.8" script)".

I guess the package tk-8.6.8 is lacked in cygwin so I try to add this package. However I can't find out this package from repository. 
Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `/usr/bin/tk86.dll` is not the cygwin shared lib. It is instead `/usr/bin/libtk8.6.dll` contained in `tcl-tk` package

Comment: actually, there is no 'bin' folder in 'usr' folder of cygwin. tcl-tk packages (tcl-tk, tcl-tk-debuginfo, tcl-tk-devel 8.6.8-1) were added to cygwin and I see that there are tcl8.6 and tk8.6 folders in cygwin/lib/.

Comment: @user136110: What?  Of course there is a /usr/bin, although /usr/bin is equivalent to /bin in a cygwin environment,

Comment: There is usr folder in cygwin, and bin folder too. Therefore I think they are not equivalent. Anyway, there is libtk8.6.dll in cygwin/bin. what should I do now?

Comment: No - /usr is not equivalent to /bin, but *within Cygwin*, /bin is equivalent to /usr/bin (it's done by essentially mounting /bin on /usr/bin).  I know nothing about PWgui-6.2, but if it's complaining about a missing /usr/bin/tk86.dll, it sounds like it's not configured to run under Cygwin.  How did you install it?

Comment: I downloaded the file qe-6.2-PWgui.tar.gz from http://www.qe-forge.org, put it in C:\cygwin64\home\, in cygwin I entered into \home folder and then run command in cygwin: tar zxvf qe-6.2-PWgui.tar.gz, it maked the folder \home\PWgui-6.2, I entered the folder \PWgui-6.2 then run ./pwgui and received the messages . I want to say that I added packages as mentioned in http://www-k3.ijs.si/kokalj/pwgui/install.html  "To use the source package you need required Tcl software, in particular Tcl + Tk + Itcl + Itk + Iwidgets".

Comment: You say you "added packages as mentioned in www-k3.ijs.si/kokalj/pwgui/install.html"; but how did you add them - via Cygwin or via some other means? You keep referring to paths using Window style path names rather than Cygwin-style pathnames; are you actually *using* Cygwin?  or just putting code under a Cygwin-owned directory? (Normally you wouldn't be putting anything under C:\cygwin64\home\ but under /home/<username>.)

Comment: I run Cygwin setup file to add packages, that is unique way to update packages to cygwin as I know.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is here: [Cannot launch git gui using cygwin on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393462/cannot-launch-git-gui-using-cygwin-on-windows), and this is essentially a duplicate question.  The problem is that 
**`gitk`** and **`git gui`** require **X11** in Cygwin.

**Solution**

Install some of the Cygwin X11 packages:

- Run the Cygwin installer again.
- Install "xinit" under the X11 category, accepting all the dependencies.

  - (Windows Start menu should now include: Cygwin-X)
- Start menu > run XWin Server
- In Cygwin shell, run

  `export DISPLAY=:0.0`
- At this point I got `"Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified"`, so to fix that set

  `enable_xauth=0` in `\bin\startxwin`

(Note:)

Will need to run XWin Server every time you reboot, and set `export DISPLAY=:0.0` every time you open a new Cygwin shell.  (Run `echo "export DISPLAY=:0.0" >>~/.profile` to have it run automatically whenever a new shell is started).

If you get `couldn't connect to display ":0.0"`, mouse over the X that should be in Windows taskbar tray, the pop-up should say something like `Cygwin/X Server:1.0`.  Use that `":1.0"` (or similar) instead as the value for `export DISPLAY`.

Comment: I have cygwin in `--non-admin`. Therefore, I did not have CygwinX in Windows start menu. However, I can use `startxwin` command to start the server. many thanks for this explanation.

Comment: This was quite helpful. Thanks
I was searching for the issue, but no answer was fixing my issue. finally
installing xinit did the job. save my day.

Answer (score 0):

Install windows Git.
Uninstall git from cygwin repo.
Set the environment Path for Git "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" and move it above C:\cygwin64\bin